# Cannot Check If MySQLi Recorded Values Successfully

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the code below to submit values to the database using PHP. I am trying to check if the query has been successfully run to save the data to the database. If cycle ends up not being TRUE even tough it successfully saves the data. What is wrong with it?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  `stsadad_cWmFRJ`.`bin` (`id` ,`time` ,`subu` ,`saba` ,`url`)
                                      VALUES (NULL , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,  '".$subu."',  '".$saba."',  '".$url."')";
$mysqli->query($sql);

if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Recorded successfully";
} else {
    echo "There's problem";
}
```

Comment: A `var_dump($sql);` would be helpful here. Also a `echo $mysqli->error`

Comment: @barissarac : Any of your column defined as `unique` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqli->query($sql); //inserting data to table
```

this code already inserts the data.

```
if($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) //Inserting data and checking its true or false.
```

This is like you insert the data two times.

**so this code will be false,  if any of your column defined `unique`**

One of this line is enough, So remove this line `$mysqli->query($sql);`

Comment: It is strange to me that inside the if statement mysqli is doing the job. I probably have to go with only if statement to add it in as well as check if it added in.